# JSPDF: Weird PDF Format

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am using `jsPDF` to convert html into PDF file.

This is what it looks like from the browser:

[image]

This is the PDF file:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
const doc = new jsPDF();
doc.html(document.getElementById('print-content')!, {
  callback: function (doc) {
    doc.save(activeSales?.ID + '.pdf');
  },
});
```

How to make it responsive when generating the pdf?

I want to generate it in `A4` width.

Comment: Have you tried an @media print?

Answer (score 1):

i know this is too late, but I faced the same issue before.

You can use another library called jsPDF-AutoTable which will make it easier for you to work with tables.

Here's the doc : https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable